# Collaborative text editor for integration into existing website

Tags: web-apps, text-editor, collaboration

I'm looking for a collaborative editor for integrating into an existing website. The editor needs to have:

- version tracking, so as to see changes committed by each user to a
  doc
- Instant messaging
- Ability to add comments to the doc, and track who they are from
- Ability to create a preview option for a document
- Ability to export the document in common formats HTML, TXT, DOC, DOCX, PDF

Naturally, for the purpose of integration, the software needs to have an API exposing this functionality to allow integration. To give context, the closest solution I've found is OnlyOffice Integration Edition, however I'd like to see if there are similar paid or open source softwares that off this functionality as well.

Comment: Do you want to host the solution on your own server, or are you OK with solutions that depend on a third party's server being accessible?

Comment: Hosting the solution would be preferred, but I'm open to solutions that require third party servers also.